# Comparing user input to getter

Tags: java

I am trying to  compare user input 'username' to get method in buyer class 'Buyer.getUser' and compare 'password' to get method in buyer class 'Buyer.getPass'
It keeps asking me to set the username and password as static in the buyer class however this still always says the login in unsucessful even if the correct input has been typed in.

User Class

```
switch (credentials) {
        case 1 : {
            System.out.println("Buyer");
            System.out.println("Enter Username: ");
            username = S.next();
            System.out.println("Enter Password: ");
            password = S.next();

                            if ((username.equals(Buyer.getUser())) && (password.equals(Buyer.getPass()))){
                                System.out.println("Login Successful");
                            }else{ 
                                System.out.println("Login unsucessful");
            break;
        }
                    }
```

Buyer Class

```
public class Buyer {

private String username;
private String password; 


public Buyer (String username, String password){
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

public String getUser(){
    return username;
}

public String getPass(){
    return password;
}
```

User Class

```
public static void buyerCredentials() {
    ArrayList<Buyer> buyer = new ArrayList<Buyer>();

    buyer.add(new Buyer("user1", "pass123"));
    buyer.add(new Buyer("user2", "pass321"));

    for (int i = 0; i < buyer.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(buyer.get(i));
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are not creating object of Buyer class and instead of object you calling variables as static reference so always you get null for username and password.

```
Buyer buyer = new Buyer();
buyer.getUser();
buyer.getPass();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create an instance of the Buyer object prior to compare it.

```
Buyer myBuyerInst = new Buyer("MyUser", "MyPass");
```

now you can compare:

```
username.equals(myBuyerInst.getUser())
```

You have to iterate through your list:

```
for(Buyer b : buyer) {
    username.equals(b.getUser()) 
}
```

Comment: I've just added that in as I already had it in another class in my program. All code is now in the question above.